# #hash scroll, with margin?

Tags: jquery

I'm using a simple url.page#hash style url, and using jquery to invoke a scroll to that ID on page.

Issue is, I also use the waypoints mod to stick a top nav of 33 pixels tall, so it ends up completely hiding the hash tag location under it (it's a 1 line bit of text)

is there a way to add margin to an ID on hash call so i can have the top of the page account for the menu hanging on?

Comment: Can you show us some of your jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `offset().top - 33` of the element you're scrolling to.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(ID).offset().top - 33
});
```

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykC9U/1/

Comment: I've been using window.location.hash = id; as the scolling agent.  Maybe i should change that to use the scroll functions.

Comment: Its not working if we going to URL with ID offset. Any way?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use css:

```
<a id="mytag" style="margin-top:-33px"></a>
```

Comment: At the Downvoter: Why? I think my old solution should work fine.